# Amazon EMR managing my spark cluster

Tags: amazon-emr

I have a spark setup on Amazon EC2 machines with 2 worker machines running. It reads data from cassandra, do some processing and write to sql server. I have heard about amazon EMR and read about it. I want a managed system where my worker machines are automatically added to my cluster if my job is taking more time and shutdown when my job gets completed.

Can I achieve this through Amazon EMR?

Answer (score 0):

The requirements are:

1. My worker machines are automatically added to my cluster if my job is taking more time.
2. Shutdown when my job gets completed.

No. 2 is definitely possible if your job is launched from the steps.  There is an option that auto-terminates cluster after the last step is completed.  Alternatively, this could also be done programatically with the SDK.

No. 1 is a little more difficult but EMR has three classes of nodes; master, core, and task.  Task nodes can be added after cluster creation.  The trigger for that would probably have to be done programatically or utilizing another Amazon service, like Lambda.